# testing a condition with istream objects

Tags: c++

I was trying to read a lot of numbers dynamically using the code below followed by `EOF` at the end:

```
vector<double> data;
double x;
while (cin >> x)
{
    data.pushback(x);
}
```

this method is working great but i would like to know what is happening with the expression below

```
cin >> x
```

Yeah, I know that it is used to input the data but how come I'm able to test conditions with it.
What happens with the expression below:

```
while (cin) or if (cin)
```

What does `cin` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) an object of class `istream` class, which can be cast to a `void*`, and the returned value is a null pointer if an error occured (this pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`).

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for reference.

Comment: i cannot say that i understood it completely coz i never knew about objects being type casted to pointers and i'm new to c++.but your answer gave me a rough idea on what's happening.very helpful.Thankssssss :)

Comment: The conversion to `void*` is an example of the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)