# getline(cin,input) with multiple lines? (C++)

Tags: c++, getline

I'm having an issue here that's giving me a hard time. So, I've got to read something in the format [please read the body as well, to understand my issue a little better]:

```
               TITLE

The text is actually from a file being redirected 
to input stream via piping in linux bash. I cannot
use ifstream or anything other than some form of cin,
of which I believe getline to be the most useful. 

etc.
```

Specifically, what's giving me a hard time is the blank space between TITLE and the body. I can't seem to think of a way to work around that using getline(cin,string).

The best I've come up with:

```
while(inputString.size() != 0)
    getline(cin,inputString);
    //process string
```

... is thrown out the window with the above-mentioned blank line.

Any ideas, guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the real issue here is your logic. Your input contains both empty and non-empty lines, so if you want to read all of them, you shouldn't rely on the length of the line. This can be done by testing the stream returned by `std::getline`, like so:

```
while (getline(cin, inputString))
{
    // Do something with inputString...
}
```

The loops reads from `cin` line by line and stops when it reaches the end of the input.

Comment: Yes! That did the charm. However, can you give me a quick explanation as to why it reads it all?

Comment: @assignment_operator `std::getline` not only modifies the stream object being read from, it also returns it. As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11063495/1336150), a stream object can be tested for validity by casting it to a `void*` pointer (or an explicit `bool` since C++11). You'll get a zero value (`false`) when there's a read error, *e.g* no more data in the stream.

Comment: Ahhh, OK, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you, I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
while(inputString.size() == 0)
```

You carry on reading while the string has size 0.

For extra clarity try this instead

```
while(inputString.empty())
```

Comment: I apologize for size(), the missing brackets was a typo in my OP. I have tried that but it identifies the blank line between TITLE and the body as 0 and bails out of the loop. Thank you nonetheless! I will try empty() in a minute.

Comment: @assignment_operator Unfortunately I initially missed the main error in your code which was that you used `!=` not `==` please see the edited answer.

Comment: unfortunately, the code exits upon the first line since TITLE != size 0. Thank you again, though!

Comment: @assignment_operator Then you have placed your while loop wrongly. Seems I misunderstood your problem, it was more basic than I realised.